# Convert byte array from utf-16 to utf-8

Tags: c++, utf-8, utf-16

I have a byte array

```
uint8_t array[] = {0x00, 0x72, 0x00, 0x6f,  0x00, 0x6f, 0x00, 0x74};
```

I know, that in text this is "root";
I have a function that should convert utf-16 to utf-8.  Here is the code:

```
inline bool convertUcs2ToUtf8(const std::vector<char> &from, std::string* const to) {
    return ucnvConvert("UTF-16", "UTF-8", from, to);
}

static inline bool ucnvConvert(const char *enc_from,
                               const char *enc_to,
                               const std::vector<char> &from,
                               std::string* const to)
{
    if (from.empty()) {
        to->clear();
        return true;
    }

    unsigned int maxOutSize = from.size() * 3 + 1;
    std::vector<char> outBuf(maxOutSize);

    iconv_t c = iconv_open(enc_to, enc_from);
    ASSERT_MSG(c != NULL, "convert: illegal encodings");
    char *from_ptr = const_cast<char*>(from.data());
    char *to_ptr = &outBuf[0];

    size_t inleft = from.size(), outleft = maxOutSize;
    size_t n = iconv(c, &from_ptr, &inleft, &to_ptr, &outleft);
    bool success = true;
    if (n == (size_t)-1) {
        success = false;
        if (errno == E2BIG) {
            ELOG("convert: insufficient space from");
        } else if (errno == EILSEQ) {
            ELOG("convert: invalid input sequence");
        } else if (errno == EINVAL) {
            ELOG("convert: incomplete input sequence");
        }
    }
    if (success) {
        to->assign(&outBuf[0], maxOutSize - outleft);
    }
    iconv_close(c);
    return success;
}
```

it works great with cyrillic (it begins with 0x04), but when I try to put my array in it, I get something like :

```
爀漀漀琀开㌀㜀
```

and so on...
What's wrong here ?

Comment: it's trying to convert from utf16-le to utf8. you need to tell it to use utf16-be by adding a flag or something to the iconv call or you could add a [byte-order-mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) to the front of the array.

Comment: Indent your code with spaces.

Comment: You are right! The worked! Thank you!

Comment: `maxOutSize` should be declared `size_t maxOutSize;`. `from_ptr` should be declared `const char *from_ptr`

Comment: @RedCollarPanda which suggestion worked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Byte order must be specified for UTF-16 input.  Since you are passing a `utf16-be` (big-endian) encoded buffer, you should prefix it with the appropriate byte-order-mark:

```
uint8_t array[] = { 0xfe, 0xff, 0x00, 0x72, 0x00, 0x6f, 0x00, 0x6f, 0x00, 0x74 };
```

But this will produce UTF-8 output with a byte order mark you might not want.  The most effective way is then to specify the endianness this way:

```
ucnvConvert("UTF-16BE", "UTF-8", from, to);
```